# IE7 Scrollbar doesn't work

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-7, scrollbar, internet-explorer-6

I am fixing bugs for IE7 and this one has me stumped. The content in this [page](http://designvillain.com/quittance/400/404.html) is larger than its containing div. IE7 is properly displaying a vertical scroll bar but the content is getting on top of the vertical scroll bar and when the user clicks the scroll button the content doesn't move. I can't imagine what is causing this. Any Ideas?

EDIT: I Have attached a screenshot of the problem:
[alt text http://img31.imageshack.us/img31/605/picture5kw.png](http://img31.imageshack.us/img31/605/picture5kw.png)

Comment: Get IE8, then fire up the developer tool, switch to IE7 mode, and have a look at the different elements and their CSS. There was nothing that caught my eye at first sight, though...

Comment: Can't, I use a mac and I don't have access to parallels right now. Also, I changed the example page above to a page that needs scroll bars.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think this is because IE7 and IE6 are not interpreting your `overflow-x` and `overflow-y` properties correctly:

```
#content_box  {
float:left;
height:456px;
margin-left:20px;
overflow-x:hidden;
overflow-y:scroll;
```

this is easy to explain for IE6: It simply doesn't know those attributes. As for why it doesn't work in IE7, maybe the explanation is [here](http://www.brunildo.org/test/Overflowxy2.html) (It's too complicated for me to understand, I haven't eaten lunch yet).

I think what might work (after a *very* cursory examination of your code, don't sue me if it doesn't) is to introduce an additional `div`container with no width set. That would auto-adjust any `width: 100%` elements inside it in a way that prevents overflows. (I assume why this is a problem in the first place is box model issues in conjuction with `margin-left: 20px`, correct?)

Comment: Im not sure I understand why introducing a new div would help the issue -

Comment: @Thomas I think your problem is that you can't control the x and y overflow in one DIV reliably in IE < 8. Therefore, distribute it on two DIVs.

Comment: @Thomas it could be, though, that your problem is fixable by simply removing all the `float: left` s. What are they for anyway?

Comment: @Thomas and why is `grey_box` position: relative? Can you try and remove that as well?

Comment: Ok so it was position:relative that was causing the problems. I was using position relative to place a couple of absolutely positioned elements, but I'll just try to cram in some extra class to control it. Thanks!

Comment: well.. I found if I remove `overflow-x:hidden`, it will be work properly in IE7.

Answer (score 4):

> IE7 scroll issue

Apply `position: relative` to container having the property overflow-y:auto;

e.g.

```
#content_box{
    position: relative;
    overflow-y:auto;
}
```

Above solution works for me.

Answer (score 1):

Is it possible to set the width of `.grey_box` to hard-coded `510px`? Because it looks like IE7 is the only one who gets this right, since `#content_box` is set to `530px` with `10px` padding, which would make all boxes inside `520px` wide, and that is somewhere out into the scrollbar. Pekka might be into something as well, with IE7 and IE6 not implementing overflows correctly.

Comment: Yeah its possible - let me try that real quick.